# Is "pending for her return" grammatical?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Is it valid to use:

> We will be pending for her return

instead of, for example:

> We look forward to her return

Answer (score 2):

In a comment. John Lawler said...

> No. *Pend* is not a normal verb in English; the adjective *pending* is used to describe unfinished tasks and decisions, but it never occurs with a human subject. *Look forward to* (not *look forward for*) is OK, and *wait for* or *await* (without a preposition) are also OK.
>
> But be careful of spelling.

Answer (score 2):

If I add a comma, remove *for*, and assume some context, the following would be okay:

> "Will you be okay?"
>   "*We will be, pending her <sup>(some person who causes bad things)</sup> return.*"

---

Used as a standalone sentence, or without a comma, it sounds far more bizarre. But since punctuation isn't syntax, and syntax can remain valid outside of context, the following would be at least *syntactically* sound:

> We will be pending her return.

However, without that aforementioned context, it's easy to try to interpret it as meaning something like this (I can't help but add the comma back in again):

> We will exist, pending her return.

But we almost never use *be* on its own. It's almost always followed by something else. Only with Shakespeare's *to be or not to be* does it stand on its own—and that's a very specific idiomatic phrase.

---

This is also possible:

> Approval is pending.

So, although it doesn't sound entirely right on its own, the following is also possible:

> Approval will be pending <sup>(once you fill out the form).</sup>

Not only can objects or concepts be pending, but so could people in some contexts:

> After fertilization of the egg, the baby will be pending.

So at least in theory (but not in any real-word use), this is at least syntactically sound—even if not very idiomatic:

> We <sup>(members of an emergency medical team)</sup> will be pending <sup>(after we receive your distress call).</sup>

---

However, not in any contrived mental exercise, nor with different punctuation, can I make the exact sentence in the question remotely possible:

> ✘ We will be pending *for* her return.

Things can be pending, but things can't be pending *for* something. (Unless it is a period of time, but that's specifically different: *Approval will be pending for hours.*)

---

So, although I can come up with meaningful variations of the original sentence, some of them more contrived than others, I can't make it work *exactly* as it's written.

Even if I could figure out a convoluted mental exercise whereby those exact words could be used, it would be so unidiomatic as to serve no useful practical purpose.

---

For the sake of completeness, here is Merriam-Webster's definition of [*pending*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pending):

> *preposition*
>   **1** : DURING
>   // their opportunity to develop trade *pending* the laborious and fruitless negotiations
>   — Theodore Hsi-En Chen
>   **2** : while awaiting
>   // *pending* approval
>   // were held in custody *pending* trial
>
> *adjective*
>   **1** : not yet decided : being in continuance
>   // the case is still *pending*
>   **2** : IMMINENT, IMPENDING

Comment: ... and then there's the eternal "pending" limbo that flags sometimes get stuck in....